# Migrate module handling of join table data

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm working with the Migrate module and I need to migrate data related by a join table. From what I can tell, Migrate module doesn't support migrating data connected by join tables, and if it does it's not at all obvious how to build migrations handling this use case.

I have a content type Person, and a content type Program. The Program content type has a multivalue entity reference field to content of type Person.

There are three source tables:

- program
- persons
- program_persons

The table program_persons indicates the relationships between a person and a program.

I am not sure how to handle this scenario with the Migrate module. How would you go about setting up Migration classes and dependent migrations? I'll keep hammering on this but I'm stumped right now. Admittedly I don't have much experience with the Migrate module but it seems like it's worth learning.

Comment: Are you using just migrate or also migrate_d2d?

Comment: Just migrate. I'm migrating data from a non-drupal system.